# Extract embedded pdf from word document(docx) file

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

Able to extract the embedded images using [XWPF] (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html). Unable to extract embedded pdf from docx file.

Can anyone please suggest something on this?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to spot what you're doing wrong....

Comment: .docx is basically a .zip file, if it is not encrypted. So I guess the pdf is in a media subdirectory. You can extract it with POI too, by checking the content type of the document relationships, but unzipping seems easier for your use-case.

Comment: As kiwiwing said, .docx is basically a .zip file, if it is not encrypted. However the pdf is a binary file inside the zipped file folder word/embeddings/, like oleObject1.bin.
I can post a solution in linux if you need.